# Dropdown CSS conflict

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

i am using bootstrap for my website and would like to integrate this dropdown http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomDropDownListStyling/index3.html into my navigation bar as the default dropdown.

I uploaded the resources & tried to implement it but no luck, here is the result:
[image]

I wanted to keep the same style on the button in the nav that toggles the dropdown and change only the dropdown itself, managed to do the exact oposite.
Here is the navigation bar code with its css: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeStardust/z5WQ4/

The CSS code for the custom dropdown as shown in the demo:

```
.wrapper-dropdown-3 {
/* Size and position */
position: relative;
width: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 10px;

/* Styles */
background: #fff;
border-radius: 7px;
border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(50,50,50,0.1);
cursor: pointer;
outline: none;

/* Font settings */
font-weight: bold;
color: #8AA8BD;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3:after {
content: "";
width: 0;
height: 0;
position: absolute;
right: 15px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -3px;
border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #8aa8bd transparent;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown {
/* Size & position */
position: absolute;
top: 140%;
left: 0;
right: 0;

/* Styles */
background: white;
border-radius: inherit;
border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.17);
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
font-weight: normal;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
list-style: none;

/* Hiding */
opacity: 0;
pointer-events: none;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li a {
display: block;
padding: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #8aa8bd;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e8ea;
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,1);
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li i {
float: right;
color: inherit;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li:first-of-type a {
border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li:last-of-type a {
border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;
border: none;
}

/* Hover state */

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li:hover a {
background: #f3f8f8;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown:after {
content: "";
width: 0;
height: 0;
position: absolute;
bottom: 100%;
right: 15px;
border-width: 0 6px 6px 6px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #fff transparent;    
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown:before {
content: "";
width: 0;
height: 0;
position: absolute;
bottom: 100%;
right: 13px;
border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) transparent;    
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3.active .dropdown {
opacity: 1;
pointer-events: auto;
}
```

I used this code in the style-sheets they provided and imported them to the document Don't know what else to do, replacing the bootstrap css doesn't seem a nice idea

How do i make that demo my default dropdown?

I'm looking for something like this:
[image]

Comment: what is your question again mate??

Comment: How to make that demo my default dropdown

Comment: Provide a fiddle where at least show/work the dropdown ...

Comment: @Danko : its there in the question, http://jsfiddle.net/pVwh9/ but OP forgot to add jquery file in it..please do the needful :)

Comment: the fiddle doesn't work...?

Comment: I forgot the JQuery library, fixed. http://jsfiddle.net/MikeStardust/z5WQ4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A start would be to add these:

```
.navbar-default .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
}

.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3 {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(50,50,50,0.1);
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #8AA8BD;
}
```

That fixes most of it though you still need to get the arrow back

Comment: That's perfect eve without the arrow, how do i fix the hoover? just the round corners, i can change the color

Comment: Fixed it myself:) Thank you very much:)